# Are there any data repositories commonly used in conjunction with arXiv?

Tags: arxiv, data, repository

I will soon be posting an article to arXiv, and I have supplementary data that is approximately 800MB in size, which I would like to make available somewhere. Are there any data repositories that are commonly used in conjunction with arXiv?

Comment: Much of this question has been addressed in [How do I get a DOI for a dataset?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/52032/how-do-i-get-a-doi-for-a-dataset)

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of relevant options for this sort of thing. These include:

- [Figshare](https://figshare.com/)
- [Zenodo](http://zenodo.org/)
- [Dryad](http://datadryad.org/)
- [Dataverse](http://dataverse.org/)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/)
- [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)

They each have a bunch of advantages and disadvantages, and they satisfy different use cases to different degrees, so have a good look and decide which one is the best fit for your needs.

Comment: Another option, especially if the data will be updated frequently, might be a personal Github account.

Comment: If the data will be updated frequently and it then yeah, a GitHub repo can be a good choice, though [they recommend each repo be kept under 1GB](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/), which leaves little leeway if the OP wants to make any sort of significant changes to the data. On the other hand, for more moderate repo sizes, GitHub is an attractive choice if you'll be making changes but want good referenceability to previous versions, since specific versions can be given DOIs through Zenodo by simply setting them as releases.

Comment: That said, I've made this post community wiki so anyone with additional resources is welcome to edit them in.