# arXiv submission with PDF and data, preferred submission strategy?

Tags: paper-submission, arxiv, preprint

arXiv does not allow PDF and other file types on the same submission. My (many)coauthors are not tex savvy, and want the paper describing the database to be in PDF format so that their (also not tex savvy) community can access it. The database is 4 files, csv & json, and small, within arXiv size limits.  The coauthors want their preferred word letterhead, which would be a long process to recreate in tex of any flavor.

I see three paths forward:

1) put the paper describing the database into tex format without their letterhead, or reducing it to an image. Be done. Incur an unknown level of coauthor confusion and wrath (they are oddly worked up about this).  I would value easy (converters that work?) solutions in this vein.

2) Have two arXiv submissions: a) the pdf of the paper b) the csv data dictionaries (2) and json databases (2). Reference b in a.

3) Write the arXiv folks asking for an exception. I'm not sure they do this.

What is my preferred submission strategy? Any other path forward? Educating my coauthors sounds slow and hard, so yes, I know it is an option, but I'd rather not.

Comment: Just to clarify: do your authors not want to use TeX at all, or do they not want a TeX source file to be available for download - even if that enables downloading of the PDF file?

Comment: How much trouble would it be for you to convert the paper to latex, including the letterhead? Maybe I’m naive, but it seems to me that if you present your coauthors with an already working solution without them having to lift a finger, they won’t require any “educating” but will simply follow the path of least resistance and say okay. The downside is you’ll have to do the work upfront before getting their official approval, so you’d want to know you can live with a scenario where they disapprove. (Also, it’s admittedly a bit sneaky, so prepare a good explanation to diffuse any tension/anger.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bit the bullet and spent three days building the letterhead in TEX. I then requested, and was granted, a size exception. It solved my problem, but was not ideal.

Answer (score 3):

I see a fourth way forward. You could upload the database to a separate [repository](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/52032/17254) and cite that in the paper. (E.g. Zenodo allows multiple files, but putting them in an archive file might be beneficial.) Then submit the PDF version of the paper to arXiv.

> 1) put the paper describing the database into tex format without their letterhead, or reducing it to an image. Be done. Incur an unknown level of coauthor confusion and wrath (they are oddly worked up about this). I would value easy (converters that work?) solutions in this vein.

Well, don't do that unless you can get your coauthors onboard. If you can convince them, you can try Word -> TeX converters. Some possiblities can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27731/128923). The letterhead might have to be handled separately, possibly as graphics that you then auto-vectorize in Inkscape or similar tools.

> 2) Have two arXiv submissions: a) the pdf of the paper b) the csv data dictionaries (2) and json databases (2). Reference b in a.

I don't think arXiv allows a separate submission for only the data. Hence suggestion #4 above.

> 3) Write the arXiv folks asking for an exception. I'm not sure they do this.

I have never heard of them making an exception, but I have also not heard about anyone asking for one. However, even if exceptions could be made, that rarely translate to "a quick process".